# What is the right way to check which tile has been clicked in a grid?

Tags: java, libgdx

Currently we handle a click in this way:

```
@Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            Vector3 v = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            camera.unproject(v);
            if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
                // er word geloopt door alle tiles in de map
                //een for loop om alle rijen te krijgen
                for (int row = 0; row < Basemap.getTiles().length; row++) {
                    //een for loop om alle tiles in de rij te krijgen
                    for (int col = 0; col < Basemap.getTiles()[row].length; col++) {
                        //er wordt een tile opgehaald op de rij en colom waar we doorheen loopen
                        Tile baseTile = Basemap.getTiles()[row][col];
                        Tile heroTile = Heromap.getTiles()[row][col];
                        Tile rangeTile = Rangemap.getTiles()[row][col];

                        if (baseTile.getBoundingBox().contains(v)) {
                            System.out.println(baseTile.getX() + " " + baseTile.getY());

                            // als er geklikt word word setclicked op true gezet
                            if (!baseTile.getClicked()) {
                                baseTile.setClicked(true);
                                heroTile.setClicked(true);
                                rangeTile.setClicked(true);

                            // er wordt gecheckt of er een held wordt aangedrukt terwijl een andere held geselecteerd is
                                if (SelectedHero != null && heroTile.getHero() != null) {
                                    //als de 2e aangedrukte held een enemy is wordt hij aangevallen
                                    if (!SelectedHero.isEnemy() && heroTile.getHero().isEnemy() && heroTile.getHero() != null && rangeTile.getColor() == Color.RED ||
                                            !SelectedHero.isEnemy() && heroTile.getHero().isEnemy() && heroTile.getHero() != null && rangeTile.getColor() == Color.PURPLE) {
                                        if (rangeTile.getColor() == Color.RED) {
                                            SelectedHero.attack(heroTile.getHero(), Heromap);
                                            Attack = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Attack.mp3"));
                                            Attack.play();
                                            SelectedHero.setMoved(true);
                                        } else if (rangeTile.getColor() == Color.PURPLE) {
                                            SelectedHero.specialAttack(heroTile.getHero(), Heromap);
                                            Attack = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Attack.mp3"));
                                            Attack.play();
                                            SelectedHero.setMoved(true);
                                        }
```

And this is a small portion of the touchDown-method. This algorithm for our strategy game was made by a classmate from my projectgroup. When I look at this code, I have the idea that it is not good neither the right way to do it. The reason behind this is that I think that it is not efficient to loop through all tiles in a grid  to check if it is clicked when a mouseclick has happened or am I wrong?

Plus, when debugging for certain purposes, it is sometimes really hard to find the problem, when something weird happens with drawing sprites on the screen. Game logic is now located in a touchDown-event and I don't feel good about that.

However, I don't know how to do it differently. Can you guys put me in the right direction or is this kind of code just right?

Is there a way to handle click event in the game-object class itself, so that the game logic can be done in that class instead of the touchDown event?

Thanks in advance, Mike

Answer (score 0):

Just get the x and y of the click position and check what tile hat corresponds to on the map.

```
If(Gdx.input.getX() == tileX) {
    do stuff
```

}

And do the same for y axis.

And yes it is inefficient to loop through all tiles if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, start to write comments in english.

Second, assuming that this is a regular grid, why don't you simply go with the following?

```
int i = (x - gridOffsetX) / tileWidth;
int j = (y - gridOffsetY) / tileHeight;
```

-> the tile at indices i, j was clicked. (for gridOffset being the coordinates of the upper left corner of the grid)

Another thing, if you have dozens of loops and conditions in each other, then it's time to split code. You might go as far as to make everything that you can name into a method. In any way, displaying attacks and weapon sounds should clearly not be a part of a method that finds a tile.